# Colocar linha final numa Tabela- Latex

Tags: latex

Estou a construir uma Tabela em Latex e está me a dar erro na linha horizontal final que coloco.

```
\begin{table}[t]

\begin{center}

\begin{tabular}{|c|r||l|}

    \hline

    \emph{Fases} & \emph{Descrição} & \emph{Função}\\

    \hline

    1º & \Construção de um Tabuleiro de Lava & \textbf{buildLava} \\

    \hline

    2 & Posição das Peças & \textbf{passosToPosition}

    \hline

\end{tabular}

\end{center}

\caption{Fases de Resolução.}

\label{tbl:tabela}

\end{table}
```

Sabem de algum comando alternativo que faça a linha final da tabela.

Comment: Qual erro que dá? Vc tentou colocar o \\ no final da linha que tem `2 & Posição das Peças & \textbf{passosToPosition}`?

Comment: Foi exatamente esse o erro. Obrigado ;)

Comment: Por nada. Eu coloquei como resposta então. Se a resposta lhe foi útil, por favor considere [marcá-la como aceita](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 4):

[Como eu comentei](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/263510/colocar-linha-final-numa-tabela-latex?noredirect=1#comment540358_263510), falta um `\\` na última linha da tabela (isto é, a linha com o conteúdo: `2 & Posição das Peças & \textbf{passosToPosition}`).

Em geral os erros do LaTeX não são os mais intuitivos, mas vale a pena se esforçar para entendê-los porque algumas vezes (como provavelmente essa) eles podem ser úteis.